# Pointer-to-pointer access

Tags: c++, pointers, tree

Can somebody explain this to me:

```
(((((*(parent))->leaves))[7])->zone_id)
```

pointers to pointers are really confusing to me. This is the expression I got from the watch in debug mode. I am trying to access to the string `zone_id` inside the last element of tree (with 10 elements, each element for different number 0-9).

EDIT: this is the whole search function, hope it is enough to understand:

```
string Tree::search(string str, node** parent, int num) {

    int value;

    if (num < str.length()) {

        value = boost::lexical_cast<int> (str.substr(num, 1));

        if ((*parent)->leaves[value] != NULL  &&  num != str.length() -1) {

            search (str, &((*parent)->leaves[value]), num+1);


        } else if (num == str.length() -1) {

            if ( (*(parent)->leaves)[value]->zone_id.empty() )
                cout<<"Yep.";
            else
                return (string) "No_results.";

        }

    } 


}
```

and structure:

```
struct node {

    string zone_id;
    node* leaves [10];

};
```

Comment: what's confusing you about it? Do you not understand why its working ? or how it should work?

Comment: Your use of double pointers for the parameter looks unnecessary to me. Why not `const node*`? Also, you only return anything when you dont't find an empty zone_id, which is certain to cause major problems (like segmentation faults) when you use the non-existant return value later.

Answer (score 5):

Well let's get rid of some brackets to simplify it a bit:

```
(*parent)->leaves[7]->zone_id
```

Now it's much easier to understand. We are dereferencing `parent` (`*parent`) which gives us a pointer to some object that has an array member called `leaves`. So we access the element of that array with index 7, which gives us another pointer, this time pointing to an object that has a member called `zone_id`. We then access that `zone_id` member.

<sup>This is all assuming there's no operator overloading involved.</sup>

Diagrammatically (an arrow is "points to"):

```
 ________     _________     ___________         ___________
| parent |-->| *parent |-->|  struct:  |   ,-->|  struct:  |
|________|   |_________|   | leaves[0] |   |   | zone_id   |
                           | leaves[1] |   |   | ...       |
                           | leaves[2] |   |
                           | leaves[3] |   |
                           | leaves[4] |   |
                           | leaves[5] |   |
                           | leaves[6] |   |
                           | leaves[7] | --'
                           | leaves[8] |
                           | ...       |
```

Comment: Beautiful diagram! Especially helpful, I imagine, for those who don't quite understand pointers intuitively yet.

Comment: Yes, that is true. I have implemented `search` function for tree, and finally at the end of search I have to access to the `zone_id` but compiler keeps getting me the error: `Run failed`. My expression is: `if ( !(*(parent)->leaves)[value]->zone_id.empty() )`

Comment: The compiler gives you that error? Or is this when you execute your program? Does it not say anything like "segementation fault" or another error?

Comment: Hey, @sftrabbit just added search function to original question, can you take a look?

Comment: @antimatter That probably means your `leaves` array doesn't have 8 elements *or* your pointers don't point to valid objects.

Comment: @antimatter Does your `leaves` array definitely have at least 8 elements? Can you show us where you define `leaves`?

Comment: @sftrabbit yes, definitely, I found this `(((((*(parent))->leaves))[7])->zone_id)` while debugging in variables section, contains my search value. Just don't know how to access it.

Comment: @antimatter Does the segmentation fault occur on that line? To fix the segmentation fault, we need to know where it occurs.

Comment: @sftrabbit strange, but compiler passes that line, does cout, and proceed to the } at the very end of function. I can send you whole header file, if you want to look closer?

Comment: @antimatter It'll be too much to debug it myself. Just put `cout`s in, like you did, until you find the place that it stops. If you suspect a line, for example, put a cout before and after it and see if you see both.

Comment: I cannot cout anything, not even in the constructor of the class. Just keeps getting me the error: `RUN FAILED (exit value 1)` :S

Comment: @antimatter That's not necessarily an error. You might just be returning 1 from `main`.

Answer (score 0):

Removing the parenthesis makes it actually easier to read, in my mind:
`(*parent)->leaves[7]->zone_id`

So, we have a pointer to a pointer of leaves. `(*parent)` makes a dereference to that pointer (so fetches what it the pointer points at). So now we have a pointer to leaves, which is an array of 10, so we use element 7, and the pointer here is used to fetch the zone_id.

It does get a bit complicated, but this is far from the most complicated structure I have seen. If it helps you, you could break it down:

```
Parent *this_parent = *parent;

Leave *leaf = this_parent->leaves[7];

... use leaf->zone_id;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
(
  (
    (
      (
        (
          *(parent)
        )
        ->leaves
      )
    )
    [7]
  )
  ->zone_id
)
```

- dereference `parent`
- access the `leaves` member
- index the `7`th element
- access the `zone_id` member.